# Using VIM on Windows to access windows server share directory

Tags: windows, vim, nerdtree

In Windows Explorer I can navigate to "\\servername\shared_directory". Is there any way I can navigate to the same directory using VIM and NERDTree?

Example:

`:NERDTree \\servername\shared_drirectory`

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to report this behavior to the NERDTree developer. I tried it myself and no, it does not work.

You could try pulling the current NERDTree from https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree or writing the [developer](http://www.vim.org/account/profile.php?user_id=7006).

Answer (score 0):

I don't use NERDTree, but both `:browse e \\servername\shared_directory` and `:e \\servername\shared_directory\filename.txt` work fine for me in gvim.

Playing with this a bit more, I see that the forward-slash syntax seems to even work with tab-completion (after I get the server and initial directory right, of course).

If NERDTree doesn't want to work with either `//servername/directory` or `\\servername\directory`, you might want to try executing a `:lcd //servername/directory` first, followed by `:NERDTree .`.

Comment: Good suggestion, this got me close, but I get the response NERDTree: No bookmark or directory found for: .

Answer (score 0):

This issue  was fixed in this branch : https://github.com/actionshrimp/nerdtree .
Download nerdtree from  https://github.com/actionshrimp/nerdtree/downloads